# Inline block removes my first space in content:before

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ykcxb8hL/1/

Bascially I need to put inline-block on my test element but when I do it removes the first space on my content before

```
 .test:before {content: " hello ";}
.test {display: inline-block;}
```

Is there any solution to this, ideally without having to put a content: after on the item before it too?

James

Comment: you could just put a space before your `<span>` it works in your fiddle

Comment: Because I'm using responsive design sometimes I dont show this and dont want to be left with a space afterwards, ideally. I'll try the white-space idea

Comment: "I need to put inline-block on my test element " - Why? Not sure I can see a reason for this.

Comment: This isnt my full website just an example to demonstrate a point

Comment: Can you not just use a margin / padding on your `:before`?

Comment: I'm still trying to think of a reason for making the same 'inline-block'

Comment: So I dont have to use floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like given below?

.test:before {content: " \a0hello ";}
.test {display: inline-block;}

Answer (score 2):

try it

```
This is a <span class="test">World</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

what about using CSS atribute `text-indent`?

add to your `.test {display:inline-block}` this: `text-indent:5px`

*choose the value of the pixels that you want or even in %*

its basic support is cross-browser

for more info on this attribute check it here:

[**TEXT-INDENT**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-indent`:

```
.test:before {
    content: "hello";
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: 5px;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yky542sg/1/).

Otherwise use a unicode space:

```
.test:before { content: "\00a0hello"; }
```